# Scala: How to return the key that contains an item in their value where value is a Set?

Tags: scala, dictionary, set

I have a `Map[Int, Set[Int]]`and given an item I want to return the key that indexes to the Set where item exists in. For example if I have a `Map(1 -> Set("a"), 2 -> Set("b"), 3 -> Set("c","z"))`. Say the item is `"z"` I want to return `3` because `3` is the key that indexes to the set that contains `3`. 
Here is what I currently have, but I can't seem to find a good way to get the key. I can only get the value, the `Set[Int]`. Assume the item will only be in one possible set.

```
def find(djs: Map[Int, Set[Int]], item: Int) :Int = {
for ((key, set) <- djs) {
  if (set.contains(item)) {
    key
  } 
}
```

Comment: What do you want to return if the item is under multiple keys?

Comment: Do you mean Set("c", "z"), or is it really a set with 1 string?

Comment: @jwvh Assume the item will only be in one possible set or none otherwise. I added to the question.

Comment: @soote I edited the question, I meant Set("c", "z").

Comment: seems that you are using a map in the wrong way...why don't u keep a map (another?) which maps an element to the Set it is in ? or maybe a `Map[Int, (Int, Set[Int])` where the second Int is the key you are looking for..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`collectFirst` is made for this:

```
val m = Map(1 -> Set("a"), 2 -> Set("b"), 3 -> Set("c","z"))

m.collectFirst{case (k,v) if v.contains("z") => k}
//> res0: Option[Int] = Some(3)
```

and I always forget `Set` can be used as a function itself (i.e. `apply` is the same as `contains`)

```
m.collectFirst{case (k,v) if v("z") => k}
//> res0: Option[Int] = Some(3)
```

Comment: This is neat! In terms of efficiency, is this best?

Comment: It traverses the list once so it's more efficient that the find/map, and probably about the same as the flatmap. But unless you really need the micro-optimisation, I think clarity matters more

Comment: And "efficiency" depends. If you're going to do a lot of these lookups, then build a reverse map,

Answer (score 2):

The find operator can work well here:

```
def find[A, B](m: Map[A, Set[B]], item: B): Option[A] = 
    m.find { case (key, set) => set.contains(item) }
     .map  { case (key, set) => key }
```

Comment: What exactly is the `.map(_._1` for?

Comment: grabs the first value in a tuple. So in this case it just returns the key.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to return one or `None` then `Option[]` would be the way to go. If returning one, many, or none is required then returning a `List[]` might be in order.

```
val m = Map(1 -> Set("a"), 2 -> Set("b"), 3 -> Set("c","z"))

m.flatMap{ case (k,vs) => if (vs.contains("z")) Seq(k) else Seq() }  // List(3)
m.flatMap{ case (k,vs) => if (vs.contains("w")) Seq(k) else Seq() }  // List()
```

Comment: Filter is a more descriptive hof for this task, no? `m.filter(_._2.contains("z")).map(_._1)`